# SML Create a function that finds numbers not divisible from list

Tags: sml

Write a function N that for a
given natural number r (2 in the example), a list of natural numbers x1..xn,
and a list of natural numbers q1..qm (n, m ≥ 0), returns a
list of length n whose i’th element is a list of the natural
numbers in the interval [xi − r, xi + r] that are not
divisible by any of the numbers in q1..qm.

`- N 2  [25, 50, 90, 11] [2,3,7]; 
    val it = [[23,25] , [] , [89] , [11, 13]] : 
    int list list`

Comment: StackOverflow is not a marketplace for solving class assignments. You have to put some work into your problem to get some help. Copy/pasting the problem statement here won't help you at all. Nobody likes to do another's job for free, without them showing the slightest of respect.

Comment: In short, show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define the function as follows:

```
fun divisible (q::qs, x) = if (x mod q = 0) then true else divisible(qs, x)
  | divisible (nil, x) = false;


fun N r xs qs = let 
  val cs = map(fn x => List.tabulate(1+2*r, fn y => x + y - r))(xs);
in 
  map(fn bs => List.filter(fn x => not (divisible(qs,x))) (bs))(cs)
end;
```

For the given example it gives:

```
- N 2  [25, 50, 90, 11] [2,3,7];
val it = [[23,25],[],[89],[11,13]] : int list list
```